# Actual XML file location while dealing with CFchart

Tags: xml, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfchart

Could anyone tell me whether I need to place xml file in a separate directory while working with coldfusion? Right now I have kept my xml file in the same directory where I have .cfm file. When I run the file(cfm) it says,

```
Could not locate the style file filename.xml
```

Here is the error:

Could not locate the style file VerticalXLabels.xml.
Ensure that the file exists and is readable.

```
The error occurred in C:\PATH\Testing_Connections.cfm: line 296
Called from C:\PATH\Testing_Connections.cfm: line 271
Called from C:\PATH\Testing_Connections.cfm: line 1

294 :         <cfchartseries  query="detail4" type="line" itemColumn="FIFTHCONN " valueColumn="FIFTHOccurances" > 
295 :        <cfchartseries  query="detail5" type="line" itemColumn="SIXTHCONN" valueColumn="SIXTHOccurances" >   
296 :        <cfchartseries  query="detail6" type="line" itemColumn="SEVENTHCONN" valueColumn="SEVENTHOccurances" >
297 :   </cfchartseries>  
298 : </cfchart>
```

Comment: Can you please post a repro case (http://www.sscce.org/, @Leigh, thanks for this URL!) of what you're seeing, instead of describing it.

Comment: Please find my update post above.

Comment: OK, but how about what I asked for in my comment (and *read the doc* I link to)?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to ask me. Could you please precisely tell me what are you expecting?

Comment: Did you read the stuff at the link I posted? And having read it, is it still unclear what a repro case is (a self contained, complete, etc one)?

Comment: The code you are using and a sample XML file would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=graphing_06.html), you can put the XML file anywhere you like, however, you must be able to access it as if you were using CFINCLUDE.

> ColdFusion uses the same rules to look for the chart style XML files as it does for files included using the cfinclude tag.